# Variables $_GET y $_POST en Woocommerce Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de eliminar un producto del carro de la compra.
El problema viene por una función propia de woocommerce([update_carta_action](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_form_handlerupdate_cart_action/)), y es que esta función no recibe los parámetros $_GET ni $_POST y por tanto no entra a realizar ninguna acción.

Comment: Y... ¿qué hacemos si no muestras siquiera dónde podría estar el error?

Comment: No he tocado el código del plugin, esa función viene por defecto con Woocommerce y debería funcionar como a todo el mundo. Solo he incluido un print_r para mostrar las variables $_GET, pero no me devuelve los parámetros que le envío al pulsar en enlace para eliminar el producto. Este enlace por supuesto es el que crea por defecto el woocommerce en la página del carrito de la compra.

Comment: Es difícil poder ofrecer una ayuda en tales condiciones. Mira [esta situación parecida a la tuya](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/5645), en ese caso la solución ha pasado por modificar archivos PHP del plugin. En tu caso revisaría que el plugin está bien configurado y si sigue fallando consultaría al creador del mismo directamente, suelen tener una sección de soporte.